# what is the Unity 2020.1.0b16 Android Support Setup error :Failed to locate untity.exe

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using unity 2020.1.0b16 an I wont to install Android Support I install it from that link [enter link description here](http://beta.unity3d.com/download/70ea0f8c4a3c/TargetSupportInstaller/UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2020.1.0b16.exe) . then I run the setup and that what happens:

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfJej.png)

at the location it was XXXXX\unity installers\Unity 2020.1.0b16
I try it the same error
so I change the location to the file that unity.exe is located

XXXXXXXXXXXX\unity installers\Unity 2020.1.0b16\Editor

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you not to use beta versions, but about your problem, I guess you are installing Android support plugin into a different folder and not the default one.

Remember, when it prompts you to select Unity installation folder, you should select default one `C:\Program Files\Unity` and not your installation folder. The installation destination folder will be asked in a different place.

Comment: I don't have that file there is no `Unity` on `C:\Program Files` i will try to use something not beta